# Loading image from url which url doesn't end in .jpg etc

Tags: ios, iphone, image, url

I am try to get the image from this url.

http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v3/getmap?type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,51.466407,-0.952418,0,0%7Cpurple-2,51.466102,-0.958293,0,0%7C&center=51.466252499999996,-0.9553555&zoom=12&key=Kmjtd%7Cluu7n162n1%2C22%3Do5-h61wh&rand=2031817700&session=4eeb5481-00f2-0000-02b7-64f1-002655800398

I can successfully get a image that url ends in .jpg etc but not from this.

I am using the following code

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Is it possible and if so how would I go about it?

Comment: Am I missing something here? `imageWithData:` takes an `NSData` object, and you're passing it an `NSURL`?

Comment: `[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", route.mapURL]]` <- why?

Comment: it is the image from this url that i have issues with ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use NSData datawithContentsOfURL

```
[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:route.mapURL]]];
```

Comment: my mistake in my original post - this is what i have but it doesnt return the image from the url.